# UE4's editor is not loading beyond 18% on an Intel Macbook Air (BigSur)

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4, game-development

I have recently started exploring game dev and wanted to do it using the Unreal Engine(4). However, the editor doesn't seem to be loading on my computer. I have displayed the UE4 window I keep having to look at upon launching the engine.

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Unreal Engine, and I don't know how long you've waited previously (do tell!), but UE4 is a massive, memory intensive engine that would struggle on any laptop (especially a Macbook). I personally use it on my laptop (an HP Pavillion) so it is possible, but there have been times when I am trying to open a project and I've had to wait for around 30 minutes for the percent to change (it was compiling shaders silently). Although, I've never seen it take too terribly long on startup (not opening a project). Try waiting for 30 minutes and see what happens (if you haven't already), otherwise I'm sure you know Unity is a lighter-weight option with comparable features.